# C# library to automatically generate values for unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I've read about a library that generates auto values for usage in unit test but could not find it. Basically, what I want was instead of:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = 5;

    Assert.AreEqual(7, ObjectUnderTest.Add(x, y));
}
```

I want to write:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    int x = Lib.Int();
    int y = Lib.Int();

    Assert.AreEqual(x + y, ObjectUnderTest.Add(x, y));
}
```

***Update:***

[AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture) is the one I'm looking for. With AutoFixture, my test will be:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    int x = fixture.CreateAnonymous<int>();
    int y = fixture.CreateAnonymous<int>();

    Assert.AreEqual(x + y, ObjectUnderTest.Add(x, y));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)!

> Pex automatically produces a small test suite with high code coverage
>   for a .NET program. To this end, Pex performs a systematic program
>   analysis (using dynamic symbolic execution, similar to path-bounded
>   model-checking) to determine test inputs for Parameterized Unit Tests.
>   Pex learns the program behavior by monitoring execution traces. Pex
>   uses a constraint solver to produce new test inputs which exercise
>   different program behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/) is a great library for creating sets of test data and objects. It uses a fluent API so it's pretty easy, IMHO, to pick up and start working with it.

Like this (not compile tested):

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    int x = Builder<int>.CreateNew().Build();
    int y = Builder<int>.CreateNew().Build();

    Assert.AreEqual(x + y, ObjectUnderTest.Add(x, y));
}
```

There's ways to create random data as well.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoPoco](http://autopoco.codeplex.com/) lets you generate objects for tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that and autogenerate values with NBuilder (http://nbuilder.org/).

If you just want random ints (that is what you will get with NBuilder) there is an easier way to do this as well, just use the built in Random class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.random.aspx

However if you want more flexibility and functionality that goes beyond simple mathematical operations i think what you really want to do is implement a data driven unit test. Check out this link, its pretty easy to set up:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527(v=VS.100).aspx

> You can set up a unit test so that instead of typing values into a test method, you can retrieve the values from a data source. The unit test is run successively for each row in the data source. This makes it easy to test a variety of input in a single test run.

Specify a range of values and the expected results and test against it.

Answer (score 0):

AutoFixture (https://github.com/AutoFixture) is a great library. It can easily generate an object with a deep hierarchy of children in one line of code.